# I tried to install git in my machine but i got a error message like below?

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, git

I tried all the possibility kindly let me know how resolve this error message and how to install git in my machine,

```
(personal)root@ubuntu:/home/shan/workspace/projects# apt-get -f install git-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git-core : Depends: git (> 1:1.7.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: have you tried **sudo apt-get update ** and **sudo apt-get build-dep git-core** yet?

Answer (score 0):

first of all u need to remove some dependency which was conflit using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get clean
```

Then add the Thirdparty Repository Using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

While adding this Press Enter

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install git git-man git-svn
```

Now your git will work fine..